function is returning nonetype instead of list
I was making a face detector using opencv, and i made two detection two frontalface haarcascades. Then i made a code which would only display the rectangle if both detectors detect at around the same area. That worked fine, but when i put that same code in a function, it would return nonetype. If i put the rectangle draw inside the function it works, but not outside.
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv #type:ignore

cap = cv.VideoCapture(0)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()

def findsimilar(f1, f2, error):
    for (x, y, w, h) in f1:
        for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in f2:
            if x1 < x+error and x1 > x-error and y1 < y+error and y1 > y-error and w1 < w+error and w1 > w-error and h1 < h+error and h1 > h-error:
                #cv.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 128, 255), 4) #putting the rectangle code here makes it work (indicating that x, y, w, h variables exist as this code works)
                return x, y, w, h #but returning the same indicates nonetype
    
    

face_classifier = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
face_classifier_2 = cv.CascadeClassifier(cv.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml")
error = 25

while True:

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    face = face_classifier.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=5, minSize=(40, 40))
    face2 = face_classifier_2.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.1, minNeighbors=15, minSize=(40, 40))
    
    x, y, w, h = findsimilar(face2, face, error)
    print(x, y, w, h)# this line and the next line do not work because for some reason, x, y ,w, h variables are Nonetype

    frame.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 128, 255), 4)

    show = cv.flip(frame, 1)
    cv.imshow('frame', show)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()

essentially, the code inside the findsimilar() function i have confirmed to be working outside the function, and it draws the rectangle just fine. even if i put the rectangle drawing code inside the function, it works and shows the correct rectangle that is showing my face, indicating these variables x,y,w,h exist . but when i want to return the same from the function, it returns Nonetype. Error message running above code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\adhri\OneDrive\Documents\Adhrit\Python\opencv.py", line 30, in <module>
    x, y, w, h = findsimilar(face2, face, error)
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable NoneType object


Do you see that you're passing face2 for f1 and face for f2?  Clearly, the function is falling through the end of the loops.

[mre] required. that code contains a lot of irrelevant stuff. this boils down to a programming mistake, not any issue involving OpenCV.

This code:
x, y, w, h = findsimilar(face2, face, error)

roundaboutly means this:

Iterate over the result from the findsimilar function and put the first 4 values into the variables x, y, w and h

For that code to work, findsimilar has to:

Return something at all
The returned item must be iterable

Your code for findsimilar is not guaranteed to satisfy either of those criteria:
def findsimilar(f1, f2, error):
    for (x, y, w, h) in f1:
        for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in f2:
            # This check:
            if x1 < x+error and x1 > x-error and y1 < y+error and y1 > y-error and w1 < w+error and w1 > w-error and h1 < h+error and h1 > h-error:
                return x, y, w, h #but returning the same indicates nonetype

Consider what happens if that if-check fails - you have no return statement for such a case. If you try to fetch the return of a function that didn't actually return anything, Python will intercept the call and give you a single None-object (and None isn't iterable).
So you should handle the case where the if-check in findsimilar fails.
There's a few ways to do that - primarily, you can do it in your main loop or inside your function call. Which one is "best" depends on your specific workflow. Doing it in the function call can look something like this:
def findsimilar(f1, f2, error):
    for (x, y, w, h) in f1:
        for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in f2:
            if x1 < x+error and x1 > x-error and y1 < y+error and y1 > y-error and w1 < w+error and w1 > w-error and h1 < h+error and h1 > h-error:
                print(x, y, w, h)
                return x, y, w, h
            else:
                return 1, 1, 1, 1

This way, you'll get to check that the values are valid before returning - and if the if-check fails for whatever reason, you'll still get some values out of it. They won't be very useful at this point, but you'll be free from the error.
You can obviously modify that code to return something else instead (or do something else). In any case, chances are that you might have to add additional code in your main loop to account for the cases where findsimilar doesn't return valid coordinate values.
Here's a full suggestion:
def findsimilar(f1, f2, error):
    for (x, y, w, h) in f1:
        for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in f2:
            if x1 < x+error and x1 > x-error and y1 < y+error and y1 > y-error and w1 < w+error and w1 > w-error and h1 < h+error and h1 > h-error:
                print(x, y, w, h)
                return True, x, y, w, h
    return False, None, None, None, None

[...]
    update_rectangle, x, y, w, h = findsimilar(face2, face, error)
    
    if update_rectangle:
        frame.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 128, 255), 4)
        show = cv.flip(frame, 1)
        cv.imshow('frame', show)

    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break


The call
x, y, w, h = findsimilar(face2, face, error)

expects a 1D list with a length 4.
If you'll move at the function declaration -
def findsimilar(f1, f2, error):
for (x, y, w, h) in f1:
    for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in f2:
        # This check:
        if x1 < x+error and x1 > x-error and y1 < y+error and y1 > y-error and w1 < w+error and w1 > w-error and h1 < h+error and h1 > h-error:
            return x, y, w, h #but returning the same indicates nonetype

See, there is no error in the call, lets break down to steps -

Function Call
First Loop Iteration
Second Inner Loop Iteration
if (condition) -> returns list
But this list will be returned only if the condition is true else there is no else condition hence after the whole iteration Nothing (None) will be returned

In order to get the desired output add a return condition. So your final code will look like
    def findsimilar(f1, f2, error) -> list[4]:
    for (x, y, w, h) in f1:
        for (x1, y1, w1, h1) in f2:
            # This check:
            if x1 < x+error and x1 > x-error and y1 < y+error and y1 > y-error and w1 < w+error and w1 > w-error and h1 < h+error and h1 > h-error:
                return x, y, w, h #but returning the same indicates nonetype
    return 0, 0, 0, 0
        

You may be thinking why the return is at last, not after if, the reason is that it is done so that the whole image matrix gets scanned before returning any false value (or not found) i.e., 0, 0, 0, 0.
